# Counting Number of Users Whose Average is Greater than X in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to find out the number of users who have scored an average of 80 or higher. I am using `Having` in my query but it is not returning the count of number of rows.

The Schema looks like:

### Results

```
user
test_no
question_no
score
```

My Query:

```
SELECT "user" FROM results WHERE (score >0) GROUP BY "user" 
        HAVING (sum(score) / count(distinct(test_no))) >= 80;
```

I get:

```
user
2
4
8
(3 rows)
```

Instead I would like to get `3` (number of rows) as the output. If I do `count("user")`, I get the count of number of tests for each user.

I understand this is related to use Group By but I need it for my Having clause. Any suggestions how I can do this is appreciated.

**Update**: Here is some sample data: http://pastebin.com/k1nH5Wzh (-1 means unanswered)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you found is good. Some minor simplifications:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   result
   WHERE  score > 0
   GROUP  BY user_id
   HAVING (sum(score) / count(DISTINCT test_no)) >= 80
   ) sub
```

- `DISTINCT` does not require parentheses.
- You can `SELECT` a constant value in the subquery. The value is irrelevant, since you are only going to count the rows. Slightly shorter and cheaper.

Don't use the reserved word `user` as column name. That's asking for trouble. I am using `user_id` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is an efficient way to do it but this seems to be working.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
   (SELECT "user" FROM results WHERE (score >0) GROUP BY "user" 
        HAVING (sum(score) / count(distinct(test_no))) >= 80)) q1;
```